# How to upload document using documentpicker in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to upload document using documentpicker. I am able to browse the document from my phone document folder but after choosing nothing is happen. I want to get that document  like (sample.text or sample.pdf) and upload it to my database server.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func bio_choose_document_btn(_ sender: Any) 
   {

        let importDocument = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypePlainText), String(kUTTypeJPEG), String(kUTTypePNG)], in: .import)
        importDocument.delegate = self
        importDocument.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        importDocument.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(importDocument, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let filepathurl = urls.first
            else {
            return
        }
        let fileName = filepathurl.lastPathComponent
        bio_no_file_choosen_lbl.text = fileName
        
        doc_webview.load(URLRequest(url: filepathurl))
        //let items = TableViewItem()
        //items?.documentname = self.bio_doc_view.text
        //self.TableView_item.append(items!)
        print("import result : \(filepathurl)")
        self.bio_documentview_tvc.reloadData()
    }
    
          

    public func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        print("view was cancelled")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I am using webview but it opens the whole document as a view. I don't want to open it. I want to retrieve the document as a folder.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank You!
Rutuparna Panda

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you get the file path (URL) of the local file and then upload the file through the file path (URL).

AFN/Alamofire Post

```
  //...
  do{
      try formData.appendPart(withFileURL: filepathurl, name: "file")
  } catch {
      DDLog("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
  //"file" is a field that is agreed with a server colleague
  //...
```

[github](https://github.com/shang1219178163/SwiftTemplet/blob/master/SwiftTemplet/Controllers/IOPFileUploadController.swift)

Comment: How to open the selected file in a view controller? I am able to browse but when i click on open nothing happen. I want to retrieve that file in my table view cell.

Comment: UIDocumentPickerViewContrller is just a file selector, if you want to read the need to add QLPreviewController to the current controller view, and handle the proxy method. It's not easy to say clearly, you see link demo, I've implemented it before, including file selection, reading, downloading, uploading functions.@RutuparnaPanda